# Handle with dynamic request that depend on the parameters

Tags: java, spring, api, apache-kafka

I'm create an API with Spring boot and I'm trying to think of the best way to handle two requests that have the same endpoint. So if the request has paramenters X, Y and Z it does A thing, else does B thing.

What is the best way to handle it? Maybe a middleware who handle the request and point to right method? Or maybe evaluate if the parameter X is null? Thanks for helping.

For Example:

Request A:

```
/payment
   {
      "holder_name": "John Doe",
      "payment_method": 
      {
         "card_number" : "5478349021823961",
         "exp_date" : "2018-10-16",
         "cvv" : "713"
      }
   }
```

Request B:

```
/payment
   {
      "holder_name": "John Doe",
      "payment_method": 
      {
         "boleto_number" : "123456789"
      }
   }
```

These two requests have the same endpoint but the payment methods are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way, depends on the specific details and needs of the application. Checking that the values are missing or null may not be the best thing to do, e.g. if you receive the four fields `card_number`, `exp_date`, `cvv`, `boleto_number` what would be the correct action to perform.

You could request the type in the json in an extra field at root level.

```
<!-- language: json -->
{
    "holder_name": "John Doe",
    "payment_method": "TICKET",
    "payment_details": {
        "ticket_number": "123456789"
    }
}
```

Or with a field indide the current payments object.

```
<!-- language: json -->
{
    "holder_name": "John Doe",
    "payment_method": {
        "type": "TICKET"
        "ticket_number": "123456789"
    }
}
```

This way you could first check the method type, and then check that the other fields and details match the fields you are expecting for that type, to then redict to the correct handler.

Also you should decide if you allow unknown fields or fields that do not belong to the specified method. For instance, if you decide not to be that strict, then receiving the 4 fields mentioned before, with the type of `CREDIR_CARD`, can be process effectively as a credit cards payment, and the extra field ignored. If you decide to be more strict, an error could be thrown indicating that unexpected fields were received.

You could use a enum to define the types.

```
public enum PaymentType {
    TICKET,
    CREDIT_CARD,
    CASH
}
```

Finally, depending whether you are using classes or map-like objects as structure for the processed json, you could use a custom converters to transform the object easily, depending on the type.